# How to add execution order for the dynamic actions in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a button to submit data from page items.
This button action defined by 2 dynamic actions:

1. submit page
2. Run a apex process which start a procedure for creating json from data which loaded in step 1

And second task need to wait first or second task don't find new data and raise error

How to add execution order for this tasks?

Comment: Do you really need dynamic actions for this ? Why not use page processing ? Create a page process after submit that launches the procedure and change the button action to "Submit page"

Comment: Also, execution order is as you see it - the "top" dynamic action executes first, the one that follows executes next etc. They all have the "sequence" property which defines the order.

Answer (score 0):

For most of APEX component you can find a "Sequence" attribute which will determinate the order of execute/render, for dynamic actions you can find it under "Execution Options", lowest sequence number will be executed first.

Comment: yeah, submit task run before execute js, but execute task start immediatly and load to db not finished by this time

Comment: If you know the average time needed after the submit task, you can add a `setTimeout` for your JS function

`setTimeout(function(){
//your code goes here
}, 500);`

500 is to set the code to run after 500 milliseconds = 0.5 seconds